# How to include decimal numbers in ":" sequence

Tags: r, sequence

I have a series of numbers that include both whole numbers and decimals.
When I try to subset this list using a series of numbers, it ignores the decimals while subsetting.
**How do I get the subset range to include decimals?**

Note: I understand that `seq`can be used to create a sequence with different decimals (e.g., [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7340705/4581200)), but what if I want to do so using *actual* values from my data instead of a newly created sequence?

Is this possible?

For example:

```
vec <- c(-1, 0, 0.5, 0.9, 1, 1.2, 1.3, 5, 5.4, 6, 7, 9)

vec[!(vec %in% 0:2)]
 [1] -1.0  0.5  0.9  1.2  1.3  5.0  5.4  6.0  7.0  9.0

#But what I want is:
 [1] -1.0  5.0  5.4  6.0  7.0  9.0
```

And

```
vec[!(vec %in% 1.2:5.4)]
 [1] -1.0  0.0  0.5  0.9  1.0  1.3  5.0  5.4  6.0  7.0  9.0

#But what I want is:
 [1] -1.0  0.0  0.5  0.9  1.0  6.0  7.0  9.0
```

Comment: How about `vec[!(vec >= 0 & vec < 2)]`?

Comment: Similarly, `setdiff(vec, vec[vec>=0 & vec<2])`

Comment: I sometimes use `\`%btwn%\` <- function(a, b) a >= min(b) & a <= max(b)`, in this case it would be `vec %btwn% 0:2`

Comment: In general, using `%in%` with decimals is a terrible idea because it is testing for equality on floats. You'll quickly run in to floating point precision problems and your next question will be a duplicate of the [Why are these numbers not equal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/903061) r-faq. For example, notice the `FALSE`s in `seq(0, 1, 0.1) %in% seq(0, 1, 0.01)`. If you want to test inclusion in a range, use `>`, `<` and the like.

Comment: Amendment to my first comment (too late to edit). In your case it would be `vec[! vec %btwn% c(1.2, 5.4)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another approach that uses `findInterval`. I find that function handy in avoiding complex nested `ifelse` constructions. In this instance it does really seem any better than the comment suggest  to use `vec[!(vec >= 0 & vec < 2)].`findInterval` returns a vector of numbers as long as its first input and can be used for indexing:

```
vec <- c(-1, 0, 0.5, 0.9, 1, 1.2, 1.3, 5, 5.4, 6, 7, 9)
vec [ findInterval(vec, c(0,2)) != 1]
#[1] -1.0  5.0  5.4  6.0  7.0  9.0
```

Simply cannot use `:` since it only supports integers.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `between` function of `dplyr` package

```
vec[!dplyr::between(vec,0,2)]
#[1] -1.0  5.0  5.4  6.0  7.0  9.0
vec[!dplyr::between(vec,1.2,5.4)]
#[1] -1.0  0.0  0.5  0.9  1.0  6.0  7.0  9.0
```